# Rails - Store API data throughout session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am rails fresher, In my rails application am fetching some large data from one site through API, each time I load page it takes time to fetch and display the data, is there any way to store this data throughout session?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure. You can just store it in memcached or redis. Community has an awesome gem for key value storages [Moneta](https://github.com/minad/moneta)

You don't posted the code, so all of the below is just an assumption.

You could just create a new `session_id` (or use existing one). Then just create new element in store with it and use it when you will need to.

```
session_id = SecureRandom.hex
store = Moneta.new(:Memcached, server: 'localhost:11211')
store[session_id] = 'value'
store[session_id] = {a: 1, b: 2}
store[session_id] = MarshallableRubyObject.new
```

Store can be expirable or you can just delete it when you don't need it anymore.